# Schedule MySQL Queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I schedule a query to run using the MySQL scheduler (if that's the best method)? I followed the instructions from the [link here](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/) but I'm a bit lost.

I would like to run the following query every 30 minutes on a particular database that we have.

```
    update REQUESTS set status='expired' where status='pending' and date_sub(now(), interval 15 minute) > req_time;
```

Comment: So you've read [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events.html) or just the tutorial?

Comment: You could look into CRON, which is another method of running code at certain time intervals.

Comment: tadman, I had read the tutorial. I just got it using the solution by juergen d. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
delimiter //
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS your_event
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 30 MINUTE 
STARTS  '2014-07-25 12:00:00'
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
DO
    update REQUESTS 
    set status='expired' 
    where status='pending' 
    and date_sub(now(), interval 15 minute) > req_time;
//
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you for your input. I also just realized that phpMyAdmin had the GUI to do events. Well at least I know how to enter this using the command prompts.